How to uninstall postgres compeletly from macbook?
I have postgres installed on my macbook using homebrew with the following command:
brew install postgresql@16
after installing it I forgot the password for my user so I decided to uninstall it and install it back again but everytime I do that it still asks me for the password for the same user from the old installation.
I tried:
brew uninstall postgresql@16

Does this help?

Do psql postgres.  If that gets you in run \du, that should show a list of users, one of which will have the same name as your OS user name. Then you can ALTER ROLE <username> WITH PASSWORD <new_password> to change the password.  Then for future reference spend some time here Client authentication.
